# How to crop an image using TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision, bounding-box

I'm trying to crop an image where I have a detected object. From TensorFlow's documentation there is a function.

```
tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, offset_height, offset_width, target_height, target_width)
```

I'm trying to work out how to get the given arguments but not sure what information to use. Here's the code I'm working with.

```
img = cv2.imread(IMAGE_PATH)
image_np = np.array(img)

input_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.expand_dims(image_np, 0), dtype=tf.float32)
detections = detect_fn(input_tensor)

num_detections = int(detections.pop('num_detections'))
detections = {key: value[0, :num_detections].numpy()
              for key, value in detections.items()}


detections['num_detections'] = num_detections
# detection_classes should be ints.
detections['detection_classes'] = detections['detection_classes'].astype(np.int64)

label_id_offset = 1
image_np_with_detections = image_np.copy()

viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
            image_np_with_detections,
            detections['detection_boxes'],
            detections['detection_classes']+label_id_offset,
            detections['detection_scores'],
            category_index,
            use_normalized_coordinates=True,
            max_boxes_to_draw=9,
            min_score_thresh=.5,
            agnostic_mode=False)

#print(detections['detection_boxes'])
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image_np_with_detections, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.show()
```

With this being the result, I'm trying to crop out everything but the bounding box -
[Identified object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXrAU.png)

Comment: Just for clarification, do you want to get the content within the bounding box as a result (e.g. list of images containing the contents of the boxes) or the remaining part without the bounding boxes?

Comment: `cv.imread` already gives a numpy array (or None). **do not do** `image_np = np.array(img)` because it's redundant

Comment: @ai2ys Yes I'm wanting to crop everything outside of the bounding box. Eventually ill run some edge detection to try count each box.

Answer (score 2):

In case the question is meant to get a solution to crop the contents of the bounding boxes and discard everything outside it should work like this:

```
# ’image’ is the input image tensor
boxes = detections['detection_boxes']

cropped_boxes = []

# this currently crops all bounding boxes, not taking into account the scores
for i in range(boxes.shape[0]):
    box = tuple(boxes[i].tolist())
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = box 
    
    # if boxes are defined relative to the image they have to 
    # get converted to image coordinates
    # y_min_image = int(y_pos_relative * img_height +.5) 
    cropped_boxes.append(
        tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(
            image=image, 
            offset_height=ymin, 
            offset_width=xmin, 
            target_height=ymax-ymin, 
            target_width=xmax-xmin
        ))
```

Infos on how the boxes can be interpreted can be found from the source code of the method `visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array` that is used in the question for drawing the results.

https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/457bcb8595903331932e2faf95bec8ba69e04688/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py

Comment: @Willumosa in case this solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help @ai2ys. I gave this a try:
image = input_tensor

And got this error:
TypeError: Cannot convert 0.31219422817230225 to EagerTensor of dtype int32

Comment: @Willumosa did you convert the image to a tf.Tensor like described in the comment

Comment: I'm using the some input_tensor from the code I shared, line 3.

Comment: @Willumosa are the bounding box dimensions defined as floating point? And probably defined relative to the image with and height? Then these have to get converted to image coordinates

Comment: I think so, how can I check? When I print detections['detection_boxes'] I get 0.36435264 0.47157788 0.6765469  0.5923345

Comment: @Willumosa You will have to calculate the locations in pixels, like described in the comment I added to the answer.